# How to change a queryset for xhtml2pdf via ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, xhtml2pdf

im trying to build a function where by the user is able to select the items he wishes to render to pdf. In order to do this, i first did some code to store the PK of the items the user selected.

(javascript)

```
var arr = []
function selector(clicked_id){
    var a = clicked_id
    if (arr.includes(a) === false){
    arr.push(a)
    document.getElementById(a).classList.add('bg-light');
    } else {
    const index = arr.indexOf(a)
    arr.splice(index, 1)
    document.getElementById(a).classList.remove('bg-light')
    }
    console.log(arr)
    console.log(a)

    };
```

(html)

```
        {%for trial in trials %}
    <td style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000" align="center" valign=middle bgcolor="#CCFFFF" id={{trial.trial_id}} onClick="return selector(this.id);"><b><font face="Arial" size=1>
    </td>
    {%endfor%}
```

As such , clicking onto the table cell will change the color of the cell and save the pk into an array. When the user clicks the button to generate the pdf , i wil pass the list of pk through into an ajax function as such :

```
function ajaxsender(clicked_id){
$.ajax({
 url : "{% url 'bom-pdf'%}",  
 method : "POST",
 data : {
   'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : "{{  csrf_token  }}",
    'arr' : arr
          },
 success : function(result) {
    console.log(arr)
    }

})};
```

(HTML)

```
        {% for product in product %}
    <a {% url 'bom-create' product.formulation_id %} id = {{product.formulation_id}} onClick="return ajaxsender(this.id);" class='btn w3-teal float-right' style="margin-right:3%">Generate BOM PDF</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is the view handling the requests:

```
def BomPdf(request):
  if request.method=='POST' and request.is_ajax():
    print('ajax requessssst')
    listy = request.POST.getlist('arr')
    print(type(listy))
    #some code here to be able to filter out my data based on the queryset passed in#
     pk = #
     data = {
         'product' : ProductFormulation.objects.filter(formulation_id = pk)[0],
     }
     pdf = render_to_pdf('rnd/bom_pdf.html', data)
     return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

The tricky part is that im using xhtml2pdf to render into a pdf , as such there is a need to retunr a httpresponse , instead of a typical jsonresponse that a view handling ajax would do. Because of this im facing a `405 error` which seems to be something related to a cors error
Therefore i have 2 questions :

1. how does one do a query using ajax and pass that into a context ?
2. how do i apply the concept in my case?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with returning any type of content to your ajax function. Javascript doesn't necessarily need to receive json, it can also receive other types of content that you then handle in your success function. However, you say you see a 405 error, meaning your view isn't returning the HttpResponse at all. Please show the full trace of the error from your django console (405 means there's an actual error being raised by Django).

Comment: Also your js function triggered on click of the `<a>` tag should suppress default behaviour. It doesn't, so probably you're seeing the GET request to the URL in href rather than your ajax request. Use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: hey , i managed to solve the issues so far , im super close to my goal , but one thing that is holding me back is the fact that the request is ajax  and that the href is non ajax. Because of this , the moment the href request is sent , it goes into the else statement which then rendered my error log , is there a way to use ajax to redirect instead of a href?

Comment: As I told you in my previous comment, remove the href attribute from you <a> tag since it shouldn't be used anyway (you want your javascript to be triggered). And inside the javascript function that you trigger with `onclick`, add `Event.preventDefault()` to prevent the browser from actually following any link in the `<a>` tag (not needed if you remove `href` but as a general rule you should do that).